# cant connect opencart to mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to set up opencart for my website, but when I fill in everything for the MySQL database I get this error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I've tried putting it on localhost, I've tried on 127.0.0.1. when I try on 192.168.1.126 (the database server) it says it can't find the database

the server hosting the PHP site is on 192.168.1.125

I'm very new to SQL, I really don't understand it fully. I'm creating a new database in SQL workbench. and filling in the info I need. How to I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your DB user is only allowed to access the DB server from 127.0.0.1. You might want to grant additional privileges to it and in your SQL shell run something like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* To 'your-db-user'@'192.168.1.125'
```

Comment: when i run that in the shell, it does nothing

Comment: It's not supposed to output anything. Can you connect to the DB now with your script?

Comment: but when i try to log on with root@192.168.1.126 i get this:  Access denied for user 'root@192.168.1.126'@'NUE-1-4' (using password: YES)        (btw NUE-1-4 is the name of the system hosting opencart (192.168.1.125) its the one trying to connect to the sql server)

Comment: Sorry - it had to be .125 instead of .126 in my command. I've modified my answer.

Comment: okay, so it worked by doing that. but i cant log into php my admin, i get this error:   #2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. <br />The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Comment: What user and host name (or IP) your phpMyAdmin uses to connect to DB? If it's not 127.0.0.1 you'll have to run the same GRANT query for this user and IP again, because the issue is exactly the same.

Comment: ive fixed that now, i just made the sql server be on the same machine that hosts phpmyadmin. but im still having problems with connecting from different machines. check my latest post for more info.

Comment: Generally it's not a very good idea to give direct access to your DB server: your application should be a secure layer between it and the user. Which means that your DB server has only to give access to your application (which only means one IP/hostname), and your application, in turn, provides the selected data to everyone else. Otherwise you expose yourself unnecessarily to possible malicious attacks.

Comment: what do you mean by direct access? to access the myphp theys till have to login

Comment: Giving DB access to phpMyAdmin is okay (more or less). Giving access to your application is okay. Giving access to everything else is not okay. It should be limited to these two, unless there's a very compelling reason to do otherwise.

Comment: there is no access to everything else. but i need help on getting DB access over lan working

Comment: I'll have a look at your other post. Did my answer solve the problem described in *this* post?